# ValueError using recursive feature elimination for SVM with rbf kernel in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, rfe

I'm trying to use the recursive feature elimination (RFE) function in scikit-learn but keep getting the error `ValueError: coef_ is only available when using a linear kernel`. I am trying to perform feature selection for a support vector classifier (SVC) using a rbf kernel. This example from the website executes fine:

```
print(__doc__)

from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.metrics import zero_one_loss

# Build a classification task using 3 informative features
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=25, n_informative=3,
                       n_redundant=2, n_repeated=0, n_classes=8,
                       n_clusters_per_class=1, random_state=0)

# Create the RFE object and compute a cross-validated score.
svc = SVC(kernel="linear")
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=svc, step=1, cv=StratifiedKFold(y, 2),
          scoring='accuracy')
rfecv.fit(X, y)

print("Optimal number of features : %d" % rfecv.n_features_)

# Plot number of features VS. cross-validation scores
import pylab as pl
pl.figure()
pl.xlabel("Number of features selected")
pl.ylabel("Cross validation score (nb of misclassifications)")
pl.plot(range(1, len(rfecv.grid_scores_) + 1), rfecv.grid_scores_)
pl.show()
```

However, simply changing the kernel type from linear to rbf, as follows, produces the error:

```
print(__doc__)

from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.metrics import zero_one_loss

# Build a classification task using 3 informative features
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=25, n_informative=3,
                       n_redundant=2, n_repeated=0, n_classes=8,
                       n_clusters_per_class=1, random_state=0)

# Create the RFE object and compute a cross-validated score.
svc = SVC(kernel="rbf")
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=svc, step=1, cv=StratifiedKFold(y, 2),
          scoring='accuracy')
rfecv.fit(X, y)

print("Optimal number of features : %d" % rfecv.n_features_)

# Plot number of features VS. cross-validation scores
import pylab as pl
pl.figure()
pl.xlabel("Number of features selected")
pl.ylabel("Cross validation score (nb of misclassifications)")
pl.plot(range(1, len(rfecv.grid_scores_) + 1), rfecv.grid_scores_)
pl.show()
```

This seems like it could be a bug, but if anyone could spot something I'm doing wrong that would be great. Also, I'm running python 2.7.6 with scikit-learn version 0.14.1.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22255881/166749).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to the expected outcome. [RFECV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html#sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV) requires the estimator to have an `coef_` which signifies the feature importances:

> estimator : object
>
> A supervised learning estimator with a fit method that updates a coef_ attribute that holds the fitted parameters. Important features must correspond to high absolute values in the coef_ array.

By changing the kernel to RBF, the [SVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC) is no longer linear and the `coef_` attribute becomes unavailable, according to the documentation:

> coef_
>
> array, shape = [n_class-1, n_features]
>
> Weights asigned to the features (coefficients in the primal problem). This is only available in the case of linear kernel.

The error is raised by SVC [(source)](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/svm/base.py#L411) when RFECV is trying to access `coef_` when the kernel is not linear.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, don't know how I missed that in the docs, it was right there in front of my face.

Comment: Hi, any quick suggestion on how to get weights for rbf kernel or any custom kernel?

Comment: @YS-L Please let me know if you know an answer for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55649352/how-to-run-rfecv-with-svc-in-sklearn. Thank you very much :)