# Recursive features elimination for support vector machine return NaN value

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, feature-selection

I am currently trying to use RFE for SVM model with following setup

```
    # get a list of models to evaluate
def get_models(min_selected_features, max_selected_features):
 models = dict()
 for i in range(min_selected_features, max_selected_features):
  model = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', probability=True)
  clf = RFE(estimator=model, n_features_to_select=i)
  models[str(i)] = Pipeline(steps=[('s',clf),('m',model)])
 return models

# evaluate a given model using cross-validation
def evaluate_model(model, X, y):
 cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
 scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
 print(scores)
 return scores

# get the models to evaluate
min_selected_features = 1
max_selected_features = 28
models = get_models(min_selected_features, max_selected_features)
# evaluate the models and store results
results, names = list(), list()
for name, model in models.items():
 scores = evaluate_model(model, X_test, y_test)
 results.append(scores)
 names.append(name)
 print('>%s %.3f (%.3f)' % (name, mean(scores), std(scores)))
# plot model performance for comparison
pyplot.boxplot(results, labels=names, showmeans=True)
pyplot.show()
```

And this is the return value of it

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:372: FitFailedWarning: 
30 fits failed out of a total of 30.
The score on these train-test partitions for these parameters will be set to nan.
If these failures are not expected, you can try to debug them by setting error_score='raise'.
```

### Below are more details about the failures:

```
30 fits failed with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 681, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 390, in fit
    Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 355, in _fit
    **fit_params_steps[name],
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/joblib/memory.py", line 349, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 893, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 850, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_rfe.py", line 222, in fit
    return self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_rfe.py", line 289, in _fit
    transform_func="square",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_base.py", line 201, in _get_feature_importances
    "when `importance_getter=='auto'`, the underlying "
ValueError: when `importance_getter=='auto'`, the underlying estimator SVC should have `coef_` or `feature_importances_` attribute. Either pass a fitted estimator to feature selector or call fit before calling transform.

  warnings.warn(some_fits_failed_message, FitFailedWarning)
[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
>1 nan (nan)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:372: FitFailedWarning: 
30 fits failed out of a total of 30.
The score on these train-test partitions for these parameters will be set to nan.
If these failures are not expected, you can try to debug them by setting error_score='raise'.
```

I've try this code with other models such as RF, DT and XGBoost and all of them work well. So how can I make it work here?

Comment: Try this: `model = svm.SVC(kernel="linear")`

Comment: Duplicate - [ValueError using recursive feature elimination for SVM with rbf kernel in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795216/valueerror-using-recursive-feature-elimination-for-svm-with-rbf-kernel-in-scikit)